# sideways crescent moon but also no moon somewhere else?

Tags: the-moon, amateur-observing, moon-phases

I live in Sumter, South Carolina and the moon looked like a crescent moon but sideways like a bowl. But when I told my friend to look at the moon they couldn't find it and they live in Buffalo, New York. I am really confused on what is happening because I couldn't find any information about it.

Comment: Did they have a clear line of sight to the moon? Thin crescents will be close to the sun and hence show up early in the morning or just after sunset, near the horizon. The sideways bowl shape is more an effect of your southern latitude.

Comment: What day and approximate time did this happen?

Answer (score 3):

> the moon looked like a crescent moon but sideways like a bowl

Yes that is a good description of how the moon would look from Sumter this morning.  It is completely normal for the moon to look like this, especially in the South. The moon's arc is lit by the sun, and the sun is almost directly below the moon from your perspective.

[image]

Simulated image of the moon from Sumter this morning.

The Moon should also have been visible from Buffalo. However, it was cloudy this morning in New York (according to the Met office).  The moon was probably behind a cloud.